# Responsive wrapping alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment, word-wrap

I am looking to achieve the following effect using CSS:

```
Browser is wide enough to fit text:    | left text             right text |
Browser isn't wide enough to fit text: |    left text    |
                                       |   right text    |
```

When the browser is wide enough to fit the text (not wrapped), the left text is aligned to the left and the right text is aligned to the right. When the browser gets smaller than the width of the left text and the right text (would normally force the text to wrap), I want the right text to move beneath the left text and for them both to be centred. Is this only possible with media queries?

I've tried applying `display: table` to a parent div and then putting `display: table-cell` on the left and right text elements, however I ended up with the following:

```
| left   right | (text has wrapped on it's own side)
| text    text |
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You make it using media queries

```
.left-text {float: left;}
.right-text {float: right;}


/*You set break point according to your requirement*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.left-text {float: none; text-align:center;}
.right-text {float: none;  text-align:center;}
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the font may not always be the same width, so I don't have a constant value to set max-width to.

Comment: That we can not do. My suggestion is, if text is long then use 768px or if text is short then use 480px